# how to select unique elements of a list in q#?

Tags: list, q#

I'm new to `q#` programming.
I have a number list:

```
1 3 2 3 2 4 5 2 3 6 4 2 1 6 3 2 1
```

Now, I want to generate unique set of numbers in `Q programming language` where final output must be: `1 2 3 4 5 6`

Comment: In c# there exists Distinct() method for a list, I believe there is something similar to Q#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no library method for this in Q#, so you'd have to implement it yourself. If the range of the possible numbers is small (up to N), you can allocate an extra array of N elements and mark all the numbers that occur in the input array. Otherwise you can sort the input array and return all numbers which differ from the one right before them and right after them.

That being said, I wonder why do you need to do this in Q#? Q# is a domain-specific language, so a lot of things which are one or two library calls in general-purpose languages can be rather inconvenient to do in Q#. It is typically much easier to do them in C# or F# driver and pass the result to Q# code as a parameter.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer. Thanks, Mariia.

Comment: Q# is not supposed to be used for general-purpose computations, it is specialized for expressing quantum algorithms. It does have classical elements like loops and arrays but they are designed to support quantum computations, not an arbitrary classical ones.